# Pickle: Import Error: No Module Named managers

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using `cPickle` and Python 2.7.14 to pickle a tuple consisting of `(LabelEncoder, NumPy array, NumPy array)` to `le_arr1_arr2.pkl` like this:

```
pickle.dump((le, arr1, arr2), open("le_arr1_arr2.pkl", "wb"))
```

I do this on an ML Engine instance (Linux machine) using `cPickle` version 1.71.

Then I copy it to my laptop (mac) and try:

`le, arr1, arr2 = pickle.load(open("le_arr1_arr2.pkl", "rb"))`

I'm using `cPickle` version 1.71 again and I get:

```
ImportError: No module named managers
```

Any idea what's going on here?  I'm very confused...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `dill` instead of `cPickle`? And does it fail in the same way?

Comment: I had this same issue, and discovered I had some instances of my script running in the background causing this error. I ran `ps ax|grep myscript.py` to find the background process and kill it.